# How to add a variable that increases when a condition is fulfilled inside an ansible-playbook?

Tags: variables, ansible

This is the module that I am using

```
  - name: copy from vm2 to vm3 test file
    synchronize:
      src: /home/ansible/test
      dest: /home/ansible/test
      mode: pull
    delegate_to: vm3
```

As you can see it copies the `test file` from `vm2 to vm3` and it works. But when I run it again it will of course overwrite it because it is named the same.

What I want to know is how do I edit the playbook so that every time I run it that it copies the `file to vm3` and gives it a new name like test2. So that if I run the playbook 5 times the files in vm3 would be called `"test1 test2 test3 test4 test5."`

I know how to do this with the bash script but this is very confusing.

Comment: There is no such tool in Ansible. Moreover, such a tool would be against the [idempotent principle](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#tasks-list) "`Modules should be idempotent, that is, running a module multiple times in a sequence should have the same effect as running it just once`". Ansible rather defines a state of the system then a procedure. The requested task would create a new file on each run.

Comment: Thank you, but what if I want to copy 20 files (or create) that are name like that

Comment: "`To create 20 files`" and "`gives it a new name ... every time I run it`" are different tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using the [copy module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html)?
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html

It can create a backup of the file before it replaces it. However I'm not sure if this is applicable to your use-case.

Comment: My way works for copying, that's not what I'm after. I want to touch a file let's say a 50 times and each file name to end with a number between 1 and 50.